# How to call a method from Prolog file in PHP

Tags: php, bash, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to incorporate **ProLog to a PHP** project that I have to do for a class in the university. The thing is that I was searching in Internet a library or a command to execute with the 'exec()' method in PHP, I could call a method with no parameters from ProLog to PHP, one that just write *"Hello World"*, that's OK, but when I try to call a method that receive a parameter, for example 'test(X).' that returns a list or a string, the command doesn't work. This is my command:

```
swipl -f testing.pl -g test(X),halt
```

When I run the command in a terminal by myself to check what it returns I found it returns an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I don't know why it's happening and I did researched a lot in here and other websites, couldn't find nothing. I would appreciate the help.

My final goal is to **execute a command from PHP to Prolog that returns a list** so I can work with the list in my PHP project.

(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, just in case.)

***-My testing.pl file:***

```
test1:-write('Hello World')

test([testing,list])
```

Comment: just surround with double quotes... assuming in testing.pl there **are** the clause terminating dots. Like `-g "test(X),halt"`

Comment: I second this. See for example also: `$ echo hello(X)`, which leads to: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token (`, whereas `$ echo "hello(X)"` works as expected.

Comment: Single quotes are even better if you do not need $-interpolation